# Wouldn't the filament tag alone suffice for this question?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

This question, [Hold torque during pause to change filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/hold-torque-during-pause-to-change-filament), has two unique tags:

- [change-colour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-colour)
- [change-filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-filament)

No other questions are tagged this way, so the tags won't really help it in a search.

Isn't the question just related to filament, so a solitary [filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filament) would be sufficient, I think?

Comment: I vote just filament. the rest make no sense / too specific. Though we need a lot more volume before tags are useful

Answer (score 1):

Having 2 change tags seem a bit over-redundant.

Tags I'd like to see for such a question are: [filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filament) and [pause](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pause). The question is about pausing the machine (in which he changes the filament).

In terms of searching there may be a need for a tag [change-filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-filament), or at least a tag [change](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change) or maybe better like @Greenonline suggests: [swap](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swap) or [changeover](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changeover)?

Comment: Hmmm... Neither `pause` nor `change` exist yet, but I see what you mean. Or `swap` or `changeover`. Actually pause could be good, as it might have other uses... why else would one want to pause a print, other than to change filament..? To change temperature? To pause overnight to avoid house fires and/or noise? These are what google just threw at me...